# How could I set UIDatePicker to show a day later from current date in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, calendar

I am trying to make an somewhat alarm app which has mandatory settings at first but the user can configure it by using the UIDatePicker.

The alarm app first has a defalut setting such as a week later from the current time, but it can be changed as the user scrolls the UIDatePicker. I searched a lot but cannot find a suitable answer.

can somebody please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the UIDatePicker date to your desired date time.

```
let numberOfDays = 6 
datePicker.date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (((24 * 60) * 60) * numberOfDays))
```

Hope it will help you..

**Swift 4.1:**

```
datePicker.date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (((24 * 60) * 60) * numberOfDays))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code when you create date picker.

```
datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: Date())
```

You can set value increase or decrease and complete your requirement.

Comment: Also change byAdding: .day, there are many option like .month, .year etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "Thursday, 19 Jan 2017"   
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "eeee, dd MM yyyy"
let date = df.date(from: dateString)
if let unwrappedDate = date {
    myDatePicker.setDate(unwrappedDate, animated: false)  //set your own date
}
```